# Remover cor total do `selection`

Tags: css

Coloquei este código em meus projetos para eliminar a cor quando algo for selecionado, entretanto as vezes "espaços em branco" que ficam são coloridos com cores que não deveriam, tem como evitar ou colocar transparente também?

```
::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode desabilitar o `user-select`, experimenta:

```css
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="noselect">
  Texto        com     espaços.          inclusive aqui >          
</p>
```

Comment: Realmente funciona mas ai eu perco completamente a funcionalidade daquele script FOKUS.. Não há alternativa ?

Comment: @user3163662 está utilizando que navegador? e pode postar o código que está aparecendo o espaço selecionado?

Comment: Nao consegui reproduzir o erro, infelizmente. Vou aceitar sua resposta, obrigado!